# DIV's Wont center

Tags: css, center

These are the three parts of my box.

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="top_content"></div>
    <div id="pageContent"></div>
    <div id="bot_content"></div>
</div>
```

They work on the page and look fine until I try to add content. The content is added via a JS menu. When the content is loaded the top box splits away from the bottom two.

Here is my css

```
#pageContent{
width:900px;
height:inherit;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}


#top_content {
background-image:url(../img/top_bg.png);
width:900px;
height:15px;
margin-top:20px;
}   
#bot_content {
background-image:url(../img/bottom_cont.png);
width:900px;
height:15px;
}
```

Any one have any idea's?

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvnjaq4k/ the only thing i did was give them a border so i could visually see them and also shrink their width for the fiddle

Comment: If they fail to center, it could be they are wrapped in another element which has a lesser width than them.

Comment: You still about buddy?

Comment: Whats up, at work atm.. but still around at various hours

Comment: I just edit above new problem

Comment: as well as that the content also center's on the external page with content on it but all i've done to it is just text.

Comment: Its best if you provide a JS Fiddle as then we can work with an example that is not working.